# Why is it called box of gum?

Tags: grammatical-number

A friend and I were having a conversation where I said "box of gums" and then I was corrected to say "box of gum". Why is it called a box of gum, when it's not a solid body of gum, but each gum is a separate object wrapped in a paper? And there are a few of them inside the box.

Comment: Have you looked up “pack” in the dictionary?  Also your title and body don’t match

Comment: I am sorry, I meant to say box, not pack.

Comment: Now it says “box” everywhere

Comment: "A box of" doesn't have to imply one object inside. Would you expect a box of air, for example, to contain only one oxygen molecule?

Comment: A pack of gum. Pack. Each **piece of gum** has a wrapper. Gees.

Comment: Gum is a mass noun. Even separate pieces of it are referred to as -pieces- of it.. Several drops of water. The bucket was filled with rocks - it is a bucket of rock.

Comment: @Mitch A bucket filled with rocks would be a bucket of rocks to me, precisely because rocks (as in individual stones) are _count_ nouns, whereas chewing gum isn’t. A bucket of rock would be a bucket filled with a lump hewn from a rock, rather than a bucket filled with individual stones.

Comment: Similarly, one would say "Do you want *some* gum?" even when offering from a box of individually wrapped pieces of gum.  So yes, as the OP observes, there is something special about the way "gum" is used.  Perhaps it has to do with the practice of chewing two pieces at a time, resulting in gum that resembles singular stuff rather than plural things.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, bucket of rock is a bad example. It is more likely a bucket -made- of rock.

Comment: So it comes down to the simple fact that gum is a mass noun, an uncountable noun. Thank you all.